# Coldfusion webservice HTTP_Port and HTTPS_Port

Tags: coldfusion, wsdl

A client sent me a WSDL file for a webservice they provide. It has two tags `wsdl:port`. One has an attribute `name="HTTP_Port"` the other `name="HTTPS_Port"`. These have a nested tag `wsdlsoap:address` that has a `location` attribute that contains an address. One http the other https accordingly. I setup the webservices in Coldfusion Administrator under `DATA '& SERVICES => Web Services`. Coldfusion is eager to use the URL provided under HTTP. A firewall rule regulates only https might be used.

How can I instruct Coldfusion to use the HTTPS-URL?

Comment: Hmmm.... so the problem is it doesn't even try it eh?  You compile the WSDL and it automatically defaults to HTTP?

Comment: I provide the path to the wsdl under the said settings and have no idea if it's possible to suggest a prefered protocol. It simply uses http that is the first listed.

Comment: Check to see if it's trying HTTPS first and failing over to HTTP. It's possible that you have a connection problem and need a CERT installed in the keystore.

Comment: Now that you say: I observed HTTP was called and didn't work because of firewall (known issue). I eliminated HTTP from the wsdl; still didn't work because of certificate. Added certificate. Success. On next occasion I'll readd the HTTP lines and see if it still works. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I had the HTTP_PORT replaced with the value of the HTTPS_PORT to get in working. I now changed it back to the original value and got an error beacuse the connection via port 80 could not be made. Looks to me like HTTP is not the fallback but the default first try.

Comment: Good to know - good tip! thanks for circling back and letting us know.